# Any Magento extension for implementing 'hamper'

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I would like to know how can I implement a 'hamper' function in Magento? I googled but still cannot find any solutions..

Bascially I would like to build a page such that the user has a 'basket' with a fixed maximum weight. He then can insert any item into the basket provided that the total weight of items does not exceed the basket capacity.

Anyone can suggest me how to implement it ? Thanks!

Comment: Here is the example that I have described http://www.deandeluca.com/GiftBaskets/SelectStuffers.aspx?starterId=1